# Cannot add more products under on category in ATG

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

When I tried to add more than 5,000 products under a single category, its taking more than 8 hours to execute. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here?  Is it the bcc deployment process that is slow or is it simply that you have an issue with the cache expiry?

Comment: No, I found the issue with the item-cache size. I found answer and its in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386706/cannot-add-more-products-under-on-category-in-atg/37391054#37391054

Comment: So please update your question and make it clearer what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the Item-cache size from 1000 to 40000 (in customCatalog.xml) for the item-descriptor "product" and 5000 for "category". Now its loading fast.